# Determine TimeZone name using Javascript running in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying something like this to get user's timezone name:

```
var dateTimeObject = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions();
dateTimeObject.timeZone;
```

Works fine but not in IE11. It's there but not defined. I am also trying jstz from http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/. Which also works in Chrome, but in IE it crashes. I cannot use momentjs. Can someone please recommend a solution for IE?

Thanks